# setTimeout in a for loop, variable not changing

Tags: javascript

I'm a bit of a beginner to JavaScript and I've been trying to figure this out for at least two hours.  If someone could explain to me why this is happening, it'll be great!

```
function slowDouble(x, callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
    callback(2 * x);
  }, 500);
}

function slowDoubleTenTimes(x, callback) {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        slowDouble(x, function(result) {
            x = result;
        });
    }

    callback(x);
}

slowDoubleTenTimes(3, function(result){
  console.log('The result of slowDoubleTenTimes is ' + result);
});
```

Logic is telling me that in `slowDoubleTenTimes`,
in the for loop, `x` should be changing.
And every time it calls `slowDouble` again in the subsequent for-loop iteration,
`x` should be different.
But `x` remains at `3`!
In fact, the resulting answer in `callback(x)` should be `3072`.
Yet, `x` changes from `3` to `6` and then remains at `6`.

Is there something about JavaScript that I don't know
that's preventing the result from changing?

Also, the weird thing is, if I put `console.log("hi")` after the for-loop,
the console prints out "hi" before `slowDouble` runs.
Shouldn't `slowDouble` run before `console.log("hi")`?
Or is there something about `setTimeout` that I'm not understanding correctly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

slowDouble does not block. So, "callback" is invoked right away.

setTimeout says, "run this function in 500 milliseconds". But, it doesn't block, which means that it continues to the next lines after it registered to be invoked in 500 ms.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by slowDouble does not block?  I thought code ran in a linear fashion, one line has to complete before the next one can be run.  So I thought the for-loop had to complete running before the callback.

Comment: If you remove the call to setTimeout and just invoke the statements right in the body of slowDouble, it will be a blocking, serial function.

Comment: I did notice that if you remove the call to setTimeout, it works, but had no idea why.  What you explained actually makes a lot more sense, so I guess this means that I'm not crazy.  Thank you!

Comment: This video may help illustrate the point further. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-sc73Y-zQA  Furthermore, I highly recommend reading this book: http://www.amazon.com/dp/0596517742

Comment: Wait, that still doesn't explain why x goes from 3 and then changes to 6 and then remains at 6.  I did notice that if you get rid of setTimeout, the program works, but is there a reason that x remains at 6?

Comment: @ChrisJeon So, does this answer your question? Or do you have further questions?

Comment: It does answer my question.  Thank you.  I'm still working on how to solve the problem, with the slowDouble setTimeout intact, but I'll figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

- JavaScript engines only have a single thread, forcing asynchronous
  events to queue waiting for execution.
- If a timer is blocked from immediately executing it will be delayed
  until the next possible point of execution (which will be longer than
  the desired delay).

http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

```
function slowDouble(x, callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
    callback(2 * x);
  }, 500);
}

function slowDoubleTenTimes(x, callback) {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        slowDouble(x, function(result) {
            x = result;
        });
    }

    callback(x);  //This will get called before the callback from timeout
                  // in slowDouble's context is called. 
                  // console.log(3)

}

slowDoubleTenTimes(3, function(result){
  console.log('The result of slowDoubleTenTimes is ' + result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you are immediately calling `slowDoubleTenTimes` with the `x` value of `3` which then invokes `slowDouble` 10 times and every call passes the value of `x` as `3`. approximately 500 ms later your callback is invoked to change the value of `x` and since the other calls to `slowDouble` have already been invoked, changing the value of `x` has no effect on those calls.